# Ipython module not found, but python shell imports correctly?

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

Why would ipython session not be able to import a module but a python shell session would? Both were executed under the same data_science environment?

```
 (data_science) C:\Users\ddonovan>python
    Python 3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 16:13:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
    >>> import pandas_datareader.data as web
    >>> exit()

    (data_science) C:\Users\ddonovan>ipython
    Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
    IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

    In [1]: import pandas as pd

    In [2]: pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like

    In [3]: import pandas_datareader.data as web
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-bc32bb8bec34> in <module>()
    ----> 1 import pandas_datareader.data as web

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you don't have `ipython` installed into the `data_science` environment.  When you call `ipython` from the CMD prompt it is defaulting back to the base Anaconda environment and launching from `C:\Program Files\anaconda3\Scripts` (or wherever the base install is located).

You can check several ways:

Using conda.  Run `conda list -n data_science ipython` from the CMD.  If IPython does not appear in the list of installed packaged, you are running from the base environment.

Using where.  Run `where ipython`.  If this does not point to a path in the `data_science` environment, then you are running from the base environment.

Using python.  Launch `ipython` from the CMD, then run

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

if the output is not a path to the `data_science` environment, you are probably running from the base environment.

---

To solve your issue, use conda to install IPython:

```
conda install ipython -n data_science
```

Comment: it doesn't appear that my ipython shell is using the current anaconda environment, how do I change this behavior?

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, i guess I thought I had installed ipython in my data_science env, but it appears that I did not...

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like they are using the same python:

```
Python 3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 16:13:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

is not the same as:

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

One way to to check this is to print the path to python executable:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\path\to\python.exe
```